# how to extract values from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

i have a string ... `"<+36.83452988, -119.79611969> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11/21/11 8:12:18 PM India Standard Time"`

I wish to extract the co-ordinates out of it. how can it be done..?

Comment: From where do you get the string? This is the description of an CLLocation. And CLLocation has properties for each value

Comment: yup ... I was confused about something now i have sorted it out... thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonas has the simple fundamental idea right, just not in your language.
It is simple and ends up with an x and y coordinate for you.

You can implement Jonas suggestion yourself with the NSString `rangeOfString:` and `substringWithRange:` methods and worry about the white space after with this line

```
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

The following code will take your example string and break it into string and float values for you, whichever you prefer.

```
NSString * string = @"<+36.83452988, -119.79611969> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 11/21/11 8:12:18 PM India Standard Time>";
NSRange startX = [string rangeOfString:@"<"];
NSRange endX = [string rangeOfString:@","];
NSRange endY = [string rangeOfString:@">"];

NSRange xRange;
xRange.location = startX.location+1;
xRange.length = endX.location - startX.location -1;

NSRange yRange;
yRange.location = (xRange.length + xRange.location) + 1;
yRange.length = endY.location - yRange.location;

float x = [[string substringWithRange:xRange] floatValue];
float y = [[string substringWithRange:yRange] floatValue];

NSLog(@"xString-- %@\nyString-- %@", [string substringWithRange:xRange], [string substringWithRange:yRange]);
NSLog(@"%f, %f", x,y);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry... before I was looking at a Java list and I did not check that this one is Objective C ... apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If the coordinates are the first part of your String you should just get substrings bases on certain characters, like that:

```
String x = s.substring(s.indexOf('<')+1, s.indexOf(',')).trim();
String y = s.substring(s.indexOf(',')+1, s.indexOf('>')).trim();
```

This is getting the part between < and , and then between , and >.

Regards

Jonas